# Covariance structures for multinomial logistic mixed models

Tags: r, inference, repeated-measures, covariance, multinomial-logit

I am using ordinal::clmm in R for analysis of ordinal repeated measures data. My understanding is that specifying random intercept: `(1|judge)` as random effects in `clmm(rating ~ temp + contact + (1|judge), data = wine)` , for example, corresponds to a compound symmetry covariance structure. I am curious if there is a way to specify more complex structures e.g. an AR(1) for repeated measures and a CS for random intercept in this function or the related clmm2 function. The idea is to be able to account for within subject correlation while taking care of lag between two measures over multiple visits. Alternatively, if there is another function that could be used for this purpose I'd be very happy to try it. Thanks in advance.